# How can I optimize a chat room query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

## Background

I'm building a simple chat client for a custom web application. I am required to store all chat logs. Also users can message individuals or groups. Think google chat (which I told my client to use instead but he insisted on custom). My database is structured so:

> Table: **ChatRoom**
>   int Primary Key *ChatRoomID*
>   varchar(64) *Name*
>
> Table **ChatMessage**
>   int Primary Key *ChatMessageID*
>   int *UserID*
>   int *ChatRoomID*
>   varchar(2000) *message*
>   datetime *date*
>
> Table **ChatUser**
>   int *ChatRoomID*
>   int *UserID*
>   int *LastMessageID*
>   Primary Key (ChatRoomID, UserID)

I am using SQL Server and will be migrating soon to mysql so the solution needs to work on both platforms.

## My problem

Assuming a user has just logged in I need to pull a list of all chat rooms with outstanding messages. My current query looks like this:

```
      SELECT DISTINCT
        cr.ChatRoomID AS id,
        cu.LastMessageID AS label
      FROM ChatRooms cr
      LEFT JOIN ChatUsers cu ON cu.ChatRoomID = cr.ChatRoomID
      LEFT JOIN ChatMessages cm ON cm.ChatRoomID = cr.ChatRoomID
      WHERE cu.UserID = :user_id
        AND cu.LastMessageID < cm.ChatMessageID
```

## The question

This seems to work rather well. However I suspect this will get inefficient when their are dozens of users, thousands of rooms, and millions of messages. How do optimize this query (or database structure) to make this request (number of chat rooms with outstanding messages for a given user) a performance scale-able query?

My primary concern is that I'm forced to use the "distinct" flag for this query. So this could be joining a temporary table to the millions before filtering down to 2 numbers.

## Example data

> Users
>   1 | Dr A
>   2 | Dr B
>   3 | Biller A
>   4 | Biller B
>   5 | Boss
>
> ChatRoom
>   1 | Doctor Group
>   2 | Billing Group
>
> ChatUser
>   Room | User | Message
>   - | - | -------
>   1    | 1    | 0
>   1    | 2    | 2
>   1    | 5    | 2
>   2    | 3    | 6
>   2    | 4    | 0
>   2    | 5    | 5
>
> Chat Message
>   ID | Room | User | Message
>   - | - | - | -------
>   1  | 1    | 5    | "How is everybody today?"
>   2  | 1    | 2    | "I'm well. Need more band aids in room 5."
>   3  | 2    | 5    | "Can someone restock Room 5 with Band aids?"
>   4  | 2    | 3    | "That's not my job get a lackey."
>   5  | 2    | 5    | "Do it anyway or your fired."
>   6  | 2    | 3    | "It's your're not your and I quit."

In this scenario user 1 and 4 are late for work and when they log in a a message will pop-up, and user 5 is in for a surprise in his billing department next time I run the query.

Comment: Can you provide  some test data for us to test and understand scalabilty aspect

Comment: And the actual ddl including indexes.

Comment: I don't know what ddl is and the indexes should be very obvious. I did add an example scenario.

Comment: ddl = data definition language (the script to create the tables). And just because the indexes should be obvious does not mean you have them properly defined. Indexes are a very critical part of optimization.

Comment: I don't need help with the indexes I need help writing a good query assuming the indexes are exactly as they appear (room == room, message == message, etc). An alternative table structure is also acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can optimize this query like this:

```
select cr.ChatRoomID AS id,
    cu.LastMessageID AS label
from ChatUsers cu inner join ChatRooms cr ON cu.ChatRoomID = cr.ChatRoomID
where cu.UserID = :user_id and 
exists (select 1 from ChatMessages cm where cm.ChatRoomID = cr.ChatRoomID and cu.LastMessageID < cm.ChatMessageID);
```

There are mainly 2 issues with your current query:

1. Left joining will also bring the blank records. Also there will be multiple records for a group which you are handling by using distinct.
2. The list of records are again joined will all message table data so if the message table will contain more data then you query is destined to get slow.

This is something similar we solved at https://www.applozic.com.

Disclaimer: I am working at Applozic.

Comment: This seems to eliminate the massive join that is the message table. But doesn't a sub query execute for every result of the wrapping query? I feel this may create a similar issue.

Comment: This way whenever a first record is fetched, the query will stop and run for the another. Another way to optimize this is save the message timestamp in the ChatUser table whenever a new message is posted and check the timestamp of the LastMessageId against the saved timestamp.